# error mensaje de confirmación de actualizacion

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Cordial saludo

Buenos dias

me pueden colaborar tengo el siguiente codigo

Codigo controller

> UpdateCalificaciones($id,$Nota1,$Nota2,$Nota3,$Notafinal);
>     }else{    header('Location:../Pages/index.php');  }
>  
>    
>
> ?>

```
function actualizardatos(){id=$('#id').val();
nota1=$('#nota1').val();
nota2=$('#nota2').val();
nota3=$('#nota3').val();
notafinal=$('#notafinal').val();
cadena ="id=" + id+
"&nota1=" + nota1 +
"&nota2="+ nota2 +
"&nota3="+nota3 +
"&notafinal="+ notafinal;
//"&asignatura="+asignatura+
//"&documento="+documento+
//"&docente="+docente+
//"&nombre="+nombre+
//"&grupo="+grupo+
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../Controller/edit.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
        if(r==1){
           alert("se ha registrado ");
        }else{
          alert("Error");
        }
    }
});
}
```

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../Controller/edit.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
        if(r==1){
           alert("se ha registrado ");
        }else{
          alert("Error");
        }
    }
});
}
```

en esta parte del codigo en vez de enviar el mensaje con el alert de se ha registrado me mande el alert de error y tengo que recargar la pagina para comprobar que el registro se ha editado.

http://localhost/web/prueba/Controller/edit.php 404 (Not Found) esta es la ruta donde es el controlador aqui esta el codigo del controlador

```
public function UpdateCalificaciones($Id,$Nota1,$Nota2,$Nota3,$NotaFinal)
    {
        $statement=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE calificaciones SET nota1=:nota1,nota2=:nota2,nota3=:nota3,notafinal=:notafinal WHERE idCalificaciones=:id");
        $statement->bindParam(':id',$Id);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota1',$Nota1);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota2',$Nota2);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota3',$Nota3);
        $statement->bindParam(':notafinal',$NotaFinal);
        if($statement->execute()){
            header('Location:../Pages/index.php');
        }else{
            header('Location:../Pages/edit.php');
        }
    }
```

me manda error el post
[image: esta el error que me mande cuando doy click en editar para actualizar los datos]

[image: me sale el mensaje de error y cuando actualizo con F5 la pagina me aparece el cambio pero me aparece el mensaje de error que mande con el alert y no me muestra el mensaje de registro con alert]

este es mi codigo php en donde esta la tabla con la información de los estudiantes

````
  

> <tbody>
>             <?php
>              $Calificaciones = $Model->getCalificaciones();
>              if($Calificaciones!=null){
>                 foreach($Calificaciones as $calificacion){
> 
>                   $datos=$calificacion[0]."||".
>                       $calificacion[1]."||".
>                       $calificacion[2]."||".
>                       $calificacion[3]."||".
>                       $calificacion[4]."||".
>                       $calificacion[5]."||".
>                       $calificacion[6]."||".
>                       $calificacion[7]."||".
>                       $calificacion[8]."||".
>                       $calificacion[9]."||".
>                       $calificacion[10];
>             ?> ```
>             <tr>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['idCalificaciones']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['Nombre'],"\n",$calificacion['Apellido']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['estudiante']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['NombreEstudiante']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['NombreAsignatura']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['codigo_grupo']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['nota1']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['nota2']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['nota3']?></td>
>             <td><?php echo $calificacion['notafinal']?></td>
>             <td><button class="btn btn-success"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editcalificaciones"  onclick="agregardatos('<?php echo
> $datos?>');"> <i class="fas fa-tasks " ></i>Editar</button></td>
>             <td><a href="calificaciones?id=<?php echo $calificacion['idCalificaciones'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"
> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eliminar"> <i class="fas
> fa-window-close" ></i> Eliminar</a></td>
>             </tr> ```
> 
> 
>        <?php
>                }
>             }
>            
>           ?>
>     </table>
````

Comment: Qué Framework es ese? No deberías acceder al archivo del controlador directamente.

Comment: buenos dias estoy trabajando php y mysql puro , trabajando mvc  pero no se porque esta dando este error intente en el js actualizar sin el id

Comment: Estás seguro que la ruta  **/web/prueba/Controller/edit.php** está bien escrita?

Comment: ok ya lo solucione era quitar dos puntos pero ahora me sale que actualiza los datos pero me sale en el alert de error en ves del alert con los datos registrados correctamente

Comment: @eduardomanjarres edita tu pregunta con el nuevo escenario para que puedan ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: la url http://localhost/web/prueba/Controller/edit.php existe? as intentado llamar a esa ruta sin pasar los parametros? o pasar la url a `get` e ir enviado parametros 1 a 1 para ver donde falla ?? que as intentado hasta ahora para ver el porque del error?

Comment: @Bryro es una petición Ajax, los datos los está mandando aquí: `data:cadena` Eduardo, no le veo sentido a hacer redirecciones desde PHP si estás trabajando con peticiones Ajax. Es mejor que vuelvas al cliente con un mensaje o un objeto que indique lo que haya ocurrido y allí si hace falta hagas la redirección. Escribiré una respuesta para explicarlo.

Comment: Ajax le muestra error porque toda petición ajax debe tener una respuesta, en este caso, su código que realiza la actualización, no retorna ninguna respuesta a ajax, por lo cuál, ajax reconoce esto como un error.

Answer (score 0):

Las peticiones Ajax son de ida y vuelta. Es importante entender eso para no hacer un spaghetti en el código. Ajax te crea como una pasarela entre cliente/servidor para llevar y traer cosas. Si en esa pasarela te vas para otro lado ya rompes el concepto mismo para el cual fue creado Ajax. Por tanto, no está bien que hagas una redirección desde PHP en una petición Ajax. Lo más coherente es que devuelvas una respuesta al cliente y en base a esa respuesta desde el cliente decides lo que hay que hacer: redirigir, mostrar un mensaje, etc.

Para más facilidad puedes trabajar con respuestas del tipo JSON, que permiten poner claves dentro con varios tipos de datos.

### JavaScript (código en el cliente)

```
function actualizardatos(){id=$('#id').val();
    var nota1=$('#nota1').val();
    var nota2=$('#nota2').val();
    var nota3=$('#nota3').val();
    var notafinal=$('#notafinal').val();
    /*Es más claro poner los datos así*/
    var mData={
                  id: id,
                  nota1: nota1,
                  nota2: nota2,
                  nota3: nota3,
                  notafinal: notafinal
               };
    $.ajax({
         method:"POST",              /*Actualmente se usa method*/
         url:"Controller/edit.php",  /*Error de ruta corregido*/
         data:mData,                 /*Cambiado nombre de la variable por uno más coherente*/
         dataType: 'json'            /*Agregamos el tipo de respuesta desde PHP*/
        /*En PHP pondremos una clave updated cuando se actualice*/
         success:function(r){
            /*Cuando status sea true significa que se registro*/
             if(r.updated){
               /*Si hay que redirigir, hazlo desde aquí, no desde PHP*/
               alert("se ha registrado... "+ r.msg);
             }else{
              /*Si hay que redirigir hazlo desde aquí, no desde PHP*/
               alert("Error: "+ r.msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### PHP (código en el servidor)

```
public function UpdateCalificaciones($Id,$Nota1,$Nota2,$Nota3,$NotaFinal)
    {
        $statement=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE calificaciones SET nota1=:nota1,nota2=:nota2,nota3=:nota3,notafinal=:notafinal WHERE idCalificaciones=:id");
        $statement->bindParam(':id',$Id);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota1',$Nota1);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota2',$Nota2);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota3',$Nota3);
        $statement->bindParam(':notafinal',$NotaFinal);
        /*
           Quizá debas refinar la lógica aquí, muchas consultas UPDATE
           no actualizan nada. Tal es el caso de una consulta a la que mandas
           los mismos datos que ya existen en alguna de las filas, 
           esa fila no se actualiza. Quizá convenga controlar aparte el estado
           del execute y de rowCount(). Aquí lo pongo junto para no liar demasiado
        */
        if($statement->execute() && $statement->rowCount()>0){
            # Esto pésimo, rompe la comunicación Ajax xxxx header('Location:../Pages/index.php');
            #Lo cambiamos con un array que será devuelto como JSON
            $r=array("updated"=>true, "msg"=>"Filas actualizadas: ".$statement->rowCount());
        }else{
            # Pésimo .... header('Location:../Pages/edit.php');
            $r=array("msg"=>"No se actualizaron filas");
        }
        /*
          En un modelo MVC deberías paras esto a la vista, 
          la cual debería tener métodos de salida para JSON
          con su debido encabezado y codificación
        */ 
        echo json_encode($r);
    }
```

Comment: en controlador tambien me toca cambiar la forma en qe se envian los datos como se puede en la linea de codigo publicado

Comment: @eduardomanjarres ¿es una pregunta? No entiendo tu comentario...

Comment: buenas tardes que si al  momento de modificar el codigo tambien tengo que modificar el codigo en el controlador en donde envio todo por POST

Comment: @eduardomanjarres al hablar de *controlador*, imagino que estás trabajando en un modelo MVC. Si es así, recibirías las peticiones POST en el Controlador, pedirías los datos al Modelo y luego los pasarías a la Vista para mostrarlos. Generalmente en la Vista tendrías varios métodos, para mostrar los datos como JSON, o como XML o como HTML según la necesidad y amplitud del proyecto. A eso se refería mi comentario en la pregunta, pero no sé si estás implementando MVC.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda , tengo una ultima pregunta como se puede cargar la modificación en la tabla una vez que yo haya modificado y no tenga que dar F5 para recargar la paginas. gracias por su ayuda y por su tiempo

Comment: @eduardomanjarres para lograr eso tendrías que usar Ajax, el cual te permite enviar/recibir datos hacia/desde el servidor y mostrarlos sin necesidad de recargar la página. Ajax parece complicado al principio pero cuando comprendes como funciona vas sobre ruedas. Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas con respuestas muy buenas, puedes buscar el término `Ajax` en la barra de búsqueda. Y si tienes dudas con el código que vayas a implementar puedes plantearlas mediante nuevas preguntas.